# SQL Server 2008: how to format the output as a currency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, localization, formatting

I have a query string which returns a value that has several decimal places. I want to format this to a currency $123.45.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL),0) 
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR 
where ORDERDATE = datediff(d,0,getdate()) 
and STATUS NOT IN (3,6)
```

I want the result in a currency with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Do you mean a "real" currency, one that can handle formatting for various cultures? Similar to the FORMAT function that started in SQL Server 2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)?

Comment: No, just a single culture (en-us) for New Zealand Dollars $#,###.00

Comment: Ok. I still added an answer that would account for the full formatting (i.e. the currency symbol, placement of the symbol, thousands separator, and decimal point). But to be clear, you _do_ want the thousands separator (as shown in the example in your comment), right?

Comment: It would be good / better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are looking for a "true" Currency format, similar to what can be achieved via the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function that started in SQL Server 2012, then you can achieve the exact same functionality via SQLCLR. You can either code the simple `.ToString("C" [, optional culture info])` yourself, or you can download the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_26091581) library (which I wrote, but this function is in the Free version) and use it just like the T-SQL `FORMAT` function.

For example:

```
SELECT SQL#.Math_FormatDecimal(123.456, N'C', N'en-us');
```

Output:

> $123.46

```
SELECT SQL#.Math_FormatDecimal(123.456, N'C', N'fr-fr');
```

Output:

> 123,46 €

This approach works in SQL Server 2005 / 2008 / 2008 R2. And, if / when you do upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server, you have the option of easily switching to the native T-SQL function by doing nothing more than changing the name `SQL#.Math_FormatDecimal` to be just `FORMAT`.

Putting this into the context of the query from the original question:

```
SELECT SQL#.Math_FormatDecimal(COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL),0), N'C', N'en-us') AS [Total]
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR 
where ORDERDATE = datediff(d,0,getdate()) 
and STATUS NOT IN (3,6)
```

**EDIT:**

OR, since it seems that only `en-us` format is desired, there is a short-cut that is just too easy: Converting from either the `MONEY` or `SMALLMONEY` datatypes using the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function has a "style" for `en-us` minus the currency symbol, but that is easy enough to add:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),
                CONVERT(MONEY, COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL), 0)),
                1) AS [Total]
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR 
where ORDERDATE = datediff(d,0,getdate()) 
and STATUS NOT IN (3,6)
```

Since the source datatype of the `SUBTOTAL` field is `FLOAT`, it first needs to be converted to `MONEY` and then converted to `VARCHAR`. But, the optional "style" is one reason I prefer `CONVERT` over `CAST`.

Comment: OK, so how do I write it to fit the code I have? if i put my query in where your fixed value of 123.456  is, it fails and says cannot nest a query inside.

Comment: @Bevan: it is just a function like COALESCE, SUM, etc. I will update my answer to use it in the context of your query.

Comment: @Bevan : answer has been updated with the actual usage.

Comment: @Bevan : I might have just found an even simpler answer that does what you want. Is the `SUBTOTAL` field a `MONEY` or `SMALLMONEY` datatype?

Comment: Hmmm. did I get it wrong, maybe...Cannot find either column "SQL#" or the user-defined function or aggregate "SQL#.Math_FormatDecimal", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: @Bevan: did you download SQL# from the website and install it? Either way, that might be a moot point now. I will adjust the new query to reflect a source datatype of `FLOAT`. (though next question would be why using `FLOAT` to store money values ;-))

Comment: he he: ask MYOB (it's their database structure!)

Comment: @Bevan, take a look at my update. I am glad that I thought to check to see if the CONVERT function had a format-specifier for MONEY ;-). And I was only asking about `FLOAT` as it is an imprecise datatype, though I think many moons ago, when I was first learning database, I did the same thing.

Comment: @Rajesh : no problem. And if you didn't see the final update, I did find an even easier method for SQL 2005 / 2008, but only for cultures that use comma as a thousands separator and a period as the decimal point.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a suggestion of the syntax to use to future-proof the search query.

```
select format(123.56789,'C2','en-US')  --$123.57 ;
select format(123.56789,'C3','en-US') --$123.568;
select format(123.56789,'C0','en-US') --$124
```

Comment: The format function is not available in SQL Server 2008.