# Formatting column data type directly in the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So, I've got this little problem:
I made a select to show some specific data and this is it

```
SELECT zona, SUM(etotal)
AS total
FROM ft (nolock)
GROUP BY zona
```

What I intend now is to be able to see the total values already as `€` values.
Which is the best way to reach this directly from the query?

Comment: Format it in application layer.

Comment: I can't do it just like that since I'm using a framework, so I'd be better if I could do it with code, changed on the framework itself.

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091515/sql-server-2008-how-to-format-the-output-as-a-currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This type of formatting should be done in application layer.**

With `SQL Server 2012+` you could use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
SELECT zona, 
       total = FORMAT(SUM(etotal), '########.##€')
FROM ft (nolock) 
GROUP BY zona;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/433421)**</kbd>

Or:

```
SELECT zona, 
       total = FORMAT(SUM(etotal), 'C', 'de-de')
FROM ft (nolock) 
GROUP BY zona;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/433422)**</kbd>

*Warning:*

I hope that you understand how `NOLOCK` works (possible dirty reads/...).