# Format cost into local currency format SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to converts costs into Vietnam and Indonesia.

Is there any way that we could format the value dynamically using the culture of the country currency?

**Example**:

7859948,84    to  7,859,948.84

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's something you should do in your **frontend** (e.g. your web site, or application) - not on the server...

Comment: Thank you @marc_s for the response . I will process data from a table and use it to send out mails from SQL server . i do not have any other **frontend** frontend` invloved in the process

Comment: Just because you *can* send email out of SQL Server doesn't mean that you *should* in all cases. Set up a scheduled process that runs outside SQL Server which queries the database, then formats & sends the email.

Comment: @ALroc Thank you for the tips , but I don't have the possibilty to to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format your data at the presentation layer, not in the database. Store it as the appropriate data type in the database (probably `money`), then format it using the correct culture in whatever application you're using to present to the user, using the user's preferred culture settings.

if you **must** do it in the database:

For SQL Server 2008R2 and earlier, you'll have to use a CLR function. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091581/1324345)

It can be done in T-SQL as of SQL Server 2012 using `FORMAT()` and the `vi-VN` culture string.

```
select 7859948.84, format(7859948.84,'N','vi-VN');
```

Yields `7.859.948,84` which, according to MS's culture settings, is the correct format for Vietnamese numbers.

But even though you *can* do it in newer versions of SQL Server, it should still be done in the presentation layer.