# How to display digits into a dollar format

Tags: sql-server

For example i have a netshare 1786234247.87 how can i add a dollar before it and a billion after the digits and round of it as $1.7 billion

Comment: sql is not made to display data. what did you use to display it ? php ? javascript ??

Comment: Your database is for storing data, that's it.  You write an application for viewing it (or a report, etc.).  That's where you format the data to make it look pretty with dollar signs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would have to convert your datatype to something else other than a float or decimal or whatever type you currently have now. It would be *much* better for you to make the transformation on the presentation layer, whether that is HTML, an SSRS report, etc.

If you don't want to accept this, then you're in for some hurt. This is what your solution will look like:

```
DECLARE @Money DECIMAL = 121343044114.52
SELECT 
    MoneyString  =  
    CASE 
        WHEN @Money BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999 THEN '$' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money), 0, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money))-5) + ' MILLION'
        WHEN @Money BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999 THEN '$' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money), 0, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money))-8) + ' BILLION'
    END
    ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money), 0, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Money))-5)
```

It has a lot of work needed, but gives you an idea of what you're going to have to do if you absolutely MUST do this.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Which sql language dialect are you asking about? Every dialect has different options to perform this.
But here's the general response for mysql, postgresql and redshift</strike>

https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-in-postgres-mysql-and-redshift.html

And here's stackoverflow for mssql
[SQL Server 2008: how to format the output as a currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091515/sql-server-2008-how-to-format-the-output-as-a-currency)

==================================

Refined answer for SQL 2012

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.456, 'C', 'en-us');
```

Comment: It is in a sql server 2012

Comment: Refined the answer for SQL 2012